# Same Query, Different Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a situation where I have two SQL Server databases that reside on the same server, we will call them `SOURCE` and `COPY`. `COPY` is a copy of `SOURCE` (via SSMS copy database feature) the only difference being that the names of the database are now different.

I now have a problem where a certain query that I have executed against `SOURCE` is lightning fast, and the exact same query on `COPY` takes about two minutes. For the life of me, I can't figure out what the reason for this might be.

I have checked all of the properties / configs for each of the databases using SSMS and everything appears to be the same, but obviously something is missing.

What could cause such a huge difference in performance?

Comment: The statistics could be out of date on the copy database, this is the most likely reason for the differences

Comment: Are you using fully qualified table names [serverName].[schemaname].[TableName]. If that's the case, these SP's needs to be modified to refer the new database name. One easy way of doing that is script our objects and do a replace all on the database name part.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your statistics are out of date, or maybe your indexes need to be rebuilt.

If you check out the execution plan for each database you should be able to see what's causing the difference.  If not, post the details of the execution plan for each and then maybe more assistance could be provided.

Comment: So the query in question is talking to view that is talking to a completely different database as well.  So I can't update statistics on that view can I?

Comment: Unless the view has an index, there's no statistics to update.  If both servers are connecting to the same linked server, then that shouldn't be the cause of the slowness.

edit: Are you able to get an execution plan to see the difference between the servers?

Comment: Yep, there is no index on the view.  I haven't been able to pull the execution plans.  Also, both of the databases in question are running on the same server.